# Format USB flash drive as readonly

Tags: format, read-only, usb-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a USB drive read only](https://superuser.com/questions/184004/make-a-usb-drive-read-only)
>   [Can you make a flashdrive read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/458749/can-you-make-a-flashdrive-read-only)

Is there any way to format a USB partition as readonly? Obviously any operating system could re-format it, but is there any way, possibly using cryptography to format a partition on the drive, so that with a password, and some driver software, the drive becomes readonly, and any attempt to modify it would result in destruction of data, but not manipulation?

I am looking for software only solutions to prevent files on the flash drive from being tampered with.

Comment: Do any of the solutions listed in "[Can you make a flashdrive read-only?](http://superuser.com/questions/458749/can-you-make-a-flashdrive-read-only)" work?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a hardware switch it can be done via some tinkering and I've posted a link below which might help. Basically if you can put an ISO/DMG on the drive which then mounts as a read-only partition you'll get your read-only. Depending on your OS it will vary how you go about doing this but thats the approach.

This link [read-only flash](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/looking-for-a-usb-flash-drive-with-read-only-or-write-protect-switch/) might help with some 3rd party software if you can't do the image yourself. Just "think" CD and you should get it working.

Comment: That link only helps if you have certain U3 drives. I will see if I can find anything about mounting a CD image on a partition.